# News on BBC today - What is “refuses to deny”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, formality

I read a headline today on BBC that states:

> North Korea **refuses to deny** Sony Pictures cyber-attack
> <sub>Source: [BBC News Asia, 2 December 2014](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-30283573)</sub>

What is the exact meaning of "refuses to deny" and what type of usage is this?

I wish to know about the underlying tone of this phrase. Is it serious? Light? In-between? Is it a formal or informal expression for *accepting* something indirectly?

I get the point that we can't write “denies to refuse” as it is ungrammatical, but I still don't see the underlying tone of this phase.

Comment: The North Korea's spokesman refused to announce that North Korea was not involved in a cyber-attack on Sony Pictures. That is what BBC news tells us in this article.

Comment: **Ed:** _Who took my cookie?_ **Ted:** _Beats me._ **Ed:** _You didn't take it, did you?_ **Ted:** _Who knows?_ **Ed:** _Will you at least deny that you took my cookie?_ **Ted:** _I won't admit it, but I won't deny it, either_. In that brief conversation, Ted has **refused to deny** that he took Ed's cookie.

Comment: I think there’s a good question here, but we need to know more about your current understanding in order for someone to give you more than you can find looking up the words yourself. What do you think this phrase means? Why do you doubt your conclusion? What do you mean by “type of usage”?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I wish to know about the underlying tone like serious, light, or sort of-regarding this phrase. Is it formal or informal expression for "accepting" something indirectly? I got the point that we can't write 'denies to refuse' as it is ungrammatical, but still I don't find the underlying tone of this phase. This is all I can explain. Thank You.

Comment: There is nothing remarkable about the meaning or tone of the sentence. North Korea won't deny responsibility for the attack, but you can guess from the complicated wording that the won't confirm that they did it either.

Answer (score 2):

Refuse = to decline (I don't want any.)
Deny = to say something is false (That's a lie!)

So, no, we cannot reverse them.

The Japanese government refuses to deny the news.
The Japanese government declines to claim the news is false. (what it means)

The Japanese government denies to refuse the news. (grammatically impossible)

Answer (score 1):

Here *to deny a cyber attack* means to say that you didn't do the cyber attack. If I deny a cyber attack it means I say that I didn't do the attack.

If I refuse to do something, it means somebody else asked me to do it, wants me to do it or expects me to do it - but I say *NO!*

In the Original Poster's example, other countries wanted or expected North Korea to deny that they attacked Sony. The North Korean government did not deny it. They didn't want to deny it.

Hope this is helpful!